# Attach to MySQL client entirely via FIFOs

Tags: mysql, bash, pipe, fifo

On a Bash script I want to keep MySQL sessions open across several sequential accesses; the common way to access MySQL is by opening an individual session for each SQL command, or set of commands, such as

```
mysql -u user -e "show tables;"
```

The limitation of this method is the loss of atomicity and lock statuses for those transactions which need to be twofold: for example, it's not possible to preserve the lock status on a table `T` for the whole length of the following twofold operation:

```
### Minimalistic example
data=$(mysql -e "\
    lock table T write;
    select col from T;
")
# ...
# parse 'data' and compute 'output' variable
# ...
mysql -e "insert into T values ($output);"
```

My approach to the solution is to keep the MySQL session open across multiple accesses by using two FIFOs and hang the process on background.

---

**Proposed solution:** 
Create the pair of FIFOs: `mkfifo IN OUT`. 
Set the MySQL-client instance in place, along with a dummy `while` to keep the pipes open and prevent `SIGPIPE` signals:

```
mysql --xml --batch --raw --skip-column-names \
    -h "$hostname" -u "$username" "$db" >IN <OUT &
while :; do sleep 1; done               <IN >OUT &
```

Then test it:

```
echo "show tables;" >OUT
read <IN
```

---

**Result:** 
It does not work. The `echo` command completes and bash steps over it, which means MySQL receives the input, but `read` hangs forever, so no output is produced. 
I discovered that eliminating the `IN` FIFO the whole task doesn't hang:

```
mysql --xml --batch --raw --skip-column-names \
    -h "$hostname" -u "$username" "$db" <OUT &
while :; do sleep 1; done               >OUT &

echo "show tables;" >OUT  # this produces the expected output
```

Is this behavior expected? Also I wonder if it is possible to run twofold operations in Bash without custom homebrews.

Comment: Did you try using append redirections (`>>`) or pipes `|` instead? Good question, good luck!

Comment: If you are not forced to use shell scripts, and have PHP installed, why not create a wrapper shell that will create piped command to an established connection. You can get started here : http://squirrelshaterobots.com/programming/php/building-a-queue-server-in-php-part-3-accepting-input-from-named-pipes/

Comment: I had the same problem with some bash scripts. At one point, it become very unhandy to manage. Then I discovered Python and it became the language of my choice. It has a module for interfacing to MySQL.

Answer (score 7):

The problem with FIFOs is that when every process that is inputting data terminates, it signals the processes that are reading (in this case `mysql`) that it's the end of the data, so it terminates.

The trick is to make sure that there is a process keeping the FIFO input alive at all times. You can do that by running a `sleep 999999999 > fifofile` in background.

Exemple:

```
#!/bin/sh

mkfifo /tmp/sqlpipe

sleep 2147483647 > /tmp/sqlpipe &
PID=$!

mysql -B -uUSER -pPASSWORD < /tmp/sqlpipe &

# all set up, now just push the SQL queries to the pipe, exemple:
echo "INSERT INTO table VALUES (...);" > /tmp/sqlpipe
echo "INSERT INTO table VALUES (...);" > /tmp/sqlpipe
echo "INSERT INTO table VALUES (...);" > /tmp/sqlpipe
cat "mysqldump.sql" > /tmp/sqlpipe
echo "DELETE FROM table WHERE ...;" > /tmp/sqlpipe

# done! terminate pipe
kill -s SIGINT $PID
rm /tmp/sqlpipe
```

In the end we terminate the `sleep` process to release the FIFO input completely. It will signal `mysql` that the input has ended and it will automatically die in consequence.

There is also an alternative that don't require FIFOs, but you will need two scripts:

**run.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh
./querygenerator.sh | mysql -B -uUSER -pPASSWORD
```

**querygenerator.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "INSERT INTO table VALUES (...);"
echo "INSERT INTO table VALUES (...);"
echo "INSERT INTO table VALUES (...);"
cat "mysqldump.sql"
echo "DELETE FROM table WHERE ...;"
```

Answer (score 1):

I developed a cheat for this kind of problem a while ago, using a unix socketpair().  It will only persist while the script is running (even in the background), but it is a lot easier to deal with that FIFOs.

> The socketpair() call creates an unnamed pair of connected sockets in the specified domain domain, of the specified type, and using the optionally specified protocol.

Below is a complete example, with the source code to the binary included.  Don't be daunted, you can play around with the idea very easily within an interactive shell:

```
local:/# ./socketpair /bin/bash
$ cat <& $DUP1 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' &
$ echo 'Hello SocketPair!' >& $DUP2
HELLO SOCKETPAIR!
$
```

Here's a simple script:

```
#!./socketpair /usr/bin/env bash
# We are now in a BASH script with a pair of linked sockets,
# $DUP1 and $DUP2

## Background job ## Received data on DUP1
(
    while read -r -u $DUP1
    do
        echo "Received: $REPLY"
    done 
) &


## Foreground task ## Sends data to DUP2
counter=0
while true
do
    echo Test $(( counter++ )) >&$DUP2
    sleep 1
done
```

and I include the source code within the script, just incase I move the script somewhere and I can't find the binary :)

```
## Source code for simple 'socketpair' binary
## Compile with "cc -o socketpair socketpair.c"
: <<'SOURCE'
--[ cut here ]--
/** 
* @file socketpair.c
* @author christopher anserson
* @date 2012-04-28
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

char* custom_itoa(int i) {
    static char output[24];
     return sprintf(output, "%d", i), output;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int sv[2]; /* the pair of socket descriptors */

    if (socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, sv) == -1) {
        perror("socketpair");
        exit(1);
    }
     setenv("DUP1", custom_itoa(sv[0]), 1);
     setenv("DUP2", custom_itoa(sv[1]), 1);

     /* now exec whatever script needed these paired sockets */
     execv(argv[1], &argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
--[cut here]--
SOURCE
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example that reproduces the locked-up behavior you describe:

```
while :; do sleep 1; done <IN >OUT

sed s/^/::/ >IN <OUT

cat IN

echo x > OUT
```

The `echo` command completes but neither `cat` nor `sed` do. Maybe playing with this example will yield some results.

I am not sure you need to do it this way, though. Maybe it would be better to have a control script that pipes to MySQL, and have MySQL write its output to a file.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit -o nounset -o pipefail

# Setup variables, hostname, names of files...

{
  echo 'BEGIN PROGRAM' >&2
  cat <<MYSQL
    # Do something to set the output file, maybe \t?
    lock table T write;
    select col from T;
    # Run a shell command to create a mysql.done file from MySQL
MYSQL
  while [[ ! -f mysql.done ]]
  do sleep 1
  done
  # Create rows to insert from MySQL output file.
  echo 'load data infile input.tsv into table T'
} | mysql --xml --batch --raw --skip-column-names -h "$hostname" -u "$username" "$db"
```

Control flow via FIFOs is more appealing than waiting for files to show up in a `while` loop; but FIFOs are surprisingly hard to get right.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old, but I was also looking for a comfortable bash mysql session implementation and didn't found something good enough for my needs, so I wrote my own one which I'd like to share with the world.

```
############### BASIC MYSQL SESSION IMPLEMENTATION FOR BASH (by Norman 

Geist 2015) #############
# requires coproc, stdbuf, mysql
#args: handle query
function mysql_check {
  local handle
  handle=(${1//_/ })
  #has right structure && is still running && we opened it?
  if [[ ${#handle[*]} == 3 ]] && ps -p ${handle[2]} 2>> /dev/null >> /dev/null && { echo "" >&${handle[1]}; } 2> /dev/null; then
    return 0
  fi
  return 1
}

# open mysql connection
#args: -u user [-H host] [-p passwd] -d db
#returns $HANDLE
function mysql_connect {
  local argv argc user pass host db HANDLEID i
  #prepare args
  argv=($*)
  argc=${#argv[*]}

  #get options
  user=""
  pass=""
  host="localhost"
  db=""
  for ((i=0; $i < $argc; i++))
  do
    if [[ ${argv[$i]} == "-h" ]]; then
      echo "Usage: -u user [-H host] [-p passwd] -d db"
      return 0
    elif [[ ${argv[$i]} == "-u" ]]; then
      i=$[$i+1]
      if [[ ${#argv[$i]} -gt 0 ]]; then
    user=${argv[$i]}
      else
    echo "ERROR: -u expects argument!"
    return 1
      fi
    elif [[ ${argv[$i]} == "-p" ]]; then
      i=$[$i+1]
      if [[ ${#argv[$i]} -gt 0 ]]; then
    pass="-p"${argv[$i]}
      else
    echo "ERROR: -p expects argument!"
    return 1
      fi
    elif [[ ${argv[$i]} == "-H" ]]; then
      i=$[$i+1]
      if [[ ${#argv[$i]} -gt 0 ]]; then
    host=${argv[$i]}
      else
    echo "ERROR: -H expects argument!"
    return 1
      fi
    elif [[ ${argv[$i]} == "-d" ]]; then
      i=$[$i+1]
      if [[ ${#argv[$i]} -gt 0 ]]; then
    db=${argv[$i]}
      else
    echo "ERROR: -d expects argument!"
    return 1
      fi
    fi
  done

  if [[ ${#user} -lt 1 || ${#db} -lt 1 ]]; then
    echo "ERROR: Options -u user and -d db are required!"
    return 1;
  fi

  #init connection and channels
  #we do it in XML cause otherwise we can't detect the end of data and so would need a read timeout O_o
  HANDLEID="MYSQL$RANDOM"
  eval "coproc $HANDLEID { stdbuf -oL mysql -u $user $pass -h $host -D $db --force --unbuffered --xml -vvv 2>&1; }" 2> /dev/null
  HANDLE=$(eval 'echo ${'${HANDLEID}'[0]}_${'${HANDLEID}'[1]}_${'${HANDLEID}'_PID}')
  if mysql_check $HANDLE; then
    export HANDLE
    return 0
  else
    echo "ERROR: Connection failed to $user@$host->DB:$db!"
    return 1
  fi
}

#args: handle query
#return: $DATA[0] = affected rows/number of sets; 
#        $DATA[1] = key=>values pairs following
#        $DATA[2]key; DATA[3]=val ...
function mysql_query {
  local handle query affected line results_open row_open cols key val 
  if ! mysql_check $1; then
    echo "ERROR: Connection not open!"
    return 1
  fi
  handle=(${1//_/ })

  #delimit query; otherwise we block forever/timeout
  query=$2
  if [[ ! "$query" =~ \;\$ ]]; then
    query="$query;"
  fi
  #send query
  echo "$query" >&${handle[1]}

  #get output
  DATA=();
  DATA[0]=0
  DATA[1]=0
  results_open=0
  row_open=0
  cols=0
  while read -t $MYSQL_READ_TIMEOUT -ru ${handle[0]} line
  do 
    #WAS ERROR?
    if [[ "$line" == *"ERROR"* ]]; then
      echo "$line"
      return 1
    #WAS INSERT/UPDATE?
    elif [[ "$line" == *"Query OK"* ]]; then
      affected=$([[ "$line" =~ Query\ OK\,\ ([0-9]+)\ rows?\ affected ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]})
      DATA[0]=$affected
      export DATA
      return 0
    fi

    #BEGIN OF RESULTS
    if [[ $line =~ \<resultset ]]; then
      results_open=1
    fi

    #RESULTS
    if [[ $results_open == 1 ]]; then
      if [[ $line =~ \<row ]]; then
    row_open=1
    cols=0
      elif [[ $line =~ \<field && $row_open == 1 ]]; then
    key=$([[ "$line" =~ name\=\"([^\"]+)\" ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]})
    val=$([[ "$line" =~ \>(.*)\<\/ ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} || echo "NULL")
    DATA[${#DATA[*]}]=$key
    DATA[${#DATA[*]}]=$val
    cols=$[$cols+1]
      elif [[ $line =~ \<\/row ]]; then
    row_open=0
    DATA[0]=$[${DATA[0]}+1]
    DATA[1]=$cols
      fi
    fi

    #END OF RESULTS
    if [[ $line =~ \<\/resultset ]]; then
      export DATA
      return 0
    fi
  done
  #we can only get here
  #if read times out O_o
  echo "$FUNCNAME: Read timed out!"
  return 1
}

#args: handle
function mysql_close {
  local handle
  if ! mysql_check $1; then
    echo "ERROR: Connection not open!"
    return 1
  fi
  handle=(${1//_/ })
  echo "exit;" >&${handle[1]}

  if ! mysql_check $1; then
    return 0
  else
    echo "ERROR: Couldn't close connection!"
    return 1
  fi
}
############### END BASIC MYSQL SESSION IMPLEMENTATION FOR BASH ################################

# Example usage
#define timeout for read command, in case of server error etc.
export MYSQL_READ_TIMEOUT=10

# Connect to db and get $HANDLE
mysql_connect -u mydbuser -d mydb -H mydbserver

#query db and get $DATA
mysql_query $HANDLE "SELECT dt_whatever from tbl_lol WHERE dt_rofl=10"

#close connection
mysql_close $HANDLE
```

NOTES:

- Save $HANDLE to a new variable after connection to open as many connections as you like
- You can't exchange $HANDLE between bash sessions
- You need linux packages "coproc" "stdbuf" "mysql"
- Return DATA is of a bash array

> ```
> $DATA[0] = affected rows/number of sets;
> $DATA[1] = number of key=>values pairs following;
> $DATA[2] = key1;
> $DATA[3] = value1;
>       [...]
> $DATA[n-1] = keyn;
> $DATA[n]   = valuen;
> ```

- Generally all queries should work, even "SELECT count(*)"

## Example how to loop the returned data of a two column query

## eg. "SELECT dt_id, dt_name FROM ..."

```
fields=2
for ((i=2; $i<$((${DATA[0]}*${DATA[1]}*$fields)); i+=$((${DATA[1]}*$fields))))
do
    field1key   = ${DATA[$i]};   #this is "dt_id"
    field1value = ${DATA[$i+1]}; #this is the value for dt_id
    field2key   = ${DATA[$i+2]}; #this is "dt_name"
    field2value = ${DATA[$i+3]}; #this is the value  for dt_name
done
```